# trouble printing text string in Delphi

Tags: delphi, printing, firemonkey

`Printer.Canvas.TextOut` causes an "undeclared identifier" error in Delphi.

How do I correct this error?

I am using Windows FMX Printer in the `uses` section in a Windows 32bit application.

I searched all the RAD Studio documentation which suggests `TextOut` should work.

Answer (score 3):

[`Canvas.TextOut()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas.TextOut) exists only in VCL's [`TCanvas`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Graphics.TCanvas), not in FMX's [`TCanvas`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas). For FMX, use [`Canvas.FillText()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.FillText) instead.